# Will react re-render only children in which some part of the state has changed or are all children that use the state are re-rendered?

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following scenario in a component.

```
export default class Dummy extends React.Component{
       state = {
          A: some data
          B: other data
          C: extra data
       }

       somefunction = () => {
           this.setState({A: changed Data});
       }

       render(){
            return(
                 <ChildA data={this.state.A} callBackFunction={this.somefunction}/>
                 <ChildB data={this.state.B}/>
                 <ChildC data={this.state.C}/>
            );
       }
}
```

That is, if State 'A' is changed, will ChildA only be re-rendered (because it is only associated with 'A') or all the children be re-rendered (because they are associated with state in general)?

Comment: What have you done to check it?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically this some function will invoke render method which result in rendering of all child components.

Try should component updates, useMemo, React.memo etc to control the defending of individual components.